# plug our own consensus in any one of ethereum client?

Tags: blockchain, cpp-ethereum, consensus, clique

Actually i try to add new consensus and will through  modifying some consensus to see its effect on transaction throughput.
so what platform should i use that provide me this facility or should i use clique platform to plug new consensus.

Answer (score 0):

> plug our own consensus in any one of ethereum client?

Take a look at Parity's Pluggable Consensus feature:

- https://wiki.parity.io/Pluggable-Consensus

You can either choose to experiment with the consensus algorithms Parity ships with (Ethash, Instant Seal, Aura), or write your own and plug it into the framework. (See the [`engines`](https://github.com/paritytech/parity-ethereum/tree/bf242552f3afb692baa6b7c08433f143dd8eefc0/ethcore/src/engines) part of their Github repository for an idea of how to do this, together with the wiki page above.) Note that everything's written in Rust.

I don't think Geth provides anything similarly pluggable, though there are various tutorials on how to get Clique working (e.g. [this](https://hackernoon.com/setup-your-own-private-proof-of-authority-ethereum-network-with-geth-9a0a3750cda8) one).